# Java BufferedImage Grayscale Degradation

Tags: java, bufferedimage, grayscale

I'm creating a simple program which accepts a gray scale image as an input and what I simply want to do is retrieve the color information of each pixel, store it in an array of objects I call PixelClass. The ultimate goal is simply to repaint the image to a new BufferedImage using the said acquired color information.

Code used to create the pixel array from a given image.

```
    public static PixelClass[][] getPixelArray(BufferedImage bi){
    int height = bi.getHeight();
    int width = bi.getWidth();
    PixelClass[][] pixelArray = new PixelClass[height][width];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++){
            pixelArray [i] [j] = new PixelClass(bi.getRGB(j, i));
        }
    }
    return pixelArray;
}
```

Code used to attempt to repaint the said image, using the array of PixelClass objects

```
    public void paintToPanel(PixelClass [][] pc, int height, int width){
    BufferedImage nbi = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < height ; i++){
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < width ; j++){
            nbi.setRGB(j, i, pc[i][j].getRGBValue());
        }
    }
    JLabel containerLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(nbi));
    containerLabel.setBounds(10,10,nbi.getHeight(), nbi.getWidth());
    this.add(containerLabel);
}
```

Links to original images

http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc4/hs1364.snc4/163667_172099429501181_100001033756527_413302_3062182_n.jpg

As you can see there is significant degradation on the quality of the image. The resulting image appear to be faded.

Comment: You only provide a link to one image, which I assume is the destination image. It's hard to see any possible degradation when you have nothing to compare to :)

Comment: Also, if you are specifically working with grayscale images, you may consider using `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY`

Comment: @Yuno: I don't know but all I can tell you is that *getRGB()/setRGB()* do **NOT** do what most people think it does.  get/setRGB modify pixel values depending on color models and these vary depending on your OS / JVM / monitor / whatever.  If you want to get/set pixels **WITHOUT HAVING JAVA MODIFYING YOUR PIXELS IN A VERY HARD TO PREDICT WAY** you'll want to directly work with the underlying int[] data buffer (of course this only works for some kind of BufferedImage).  As a bonus, manipulating int[] instead of set/getRGB can be as much as 100 times faster (measured on OS X 10.4).

Comment: I had a feeling it may be related to the color model.  Can you retrieve the color model and set it on the new image to maintain? Although, like you said, it's probably faster to manipulate the pixels directly.

Comment: How do i manipulate this so called underlying int[] data buffer? 
@D.N, I've tried setting the image type to type_byte_gray but still nothing happens, thing is, using the same code, no fading effect occurs when the image used is not grayscale.

Comment: @yuno what exactly are you trying to do with the source image?  It's hard to tell what your desired result is from your question.  just copy it?

Comment: I'm trying to do some image processing on grayscale images in java. In relation to this, I need to be able to obtain the pixel information of the image. Which I do by manually extracting the value of each pixel. Now when I try to redraw the image using the acquired pixel information, the resulting image seems to fade.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the MemoryImageSource class. Something like :

```
byte[] pixels = // your pixels
ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY); 
int bits[] = new int[] {8};

ColorModel cm = new ComponentColorModel(cs, bits, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE, DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

MemoryImageSource mis = new MemoryImageSource(width, height, cm, pixels, 0, width);

Image im = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(mis);
```